# Cannot get ManyToMany to work with lists of items in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, criteria

I am developing a Hibernate app and am having trouble with criteria and searching articles, here is the article class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer articleId;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="ARTICLE_CATEGORY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="ARTICLE_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="CATEGORY_ID")
    )
    private List<Category> categories;

}
```

Here is Category:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private Collection<Article> articles;
```

I use the criteria search(categories is a List):

```
return sessionFactory
    .getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(Article.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .add(Restrictions.in("categories",categories))
    .list()
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query as follows:

1. You extract the category ids from the `categories` list:

   ```
   List<Long> ids = categories.stream()
       .map(Category::getId)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. You then pass the ids list to the Criteria query:

   ```
   return sessionFactory
       .getCurrentSession()
       .createCriteria(Article.class)
       .createAlias("categories", "c")
       .add( Restrictions.in( "c.id", ids ) )
       .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
       .list();
   ```